# Calculate LookAt like function in 2 dimensions

Tags: python, math, geometry, 2d

I'm trying to create a lookAt function in 2 dimensions using Python, so here's my code right now.

```
from math import *

def lookAt(segment, originPoint):
    segmentCenterPoint = getSegmentCenter(segment)
    for i in range(2):
        vtx = getVertex(segment, i)
        x, y = getVertexCoord(vtx)
        # Calculate the rotation angle already applied on the polygon
        offsetAngle = atan2(y - segmentCenterPoint.y, x - segmentCenterPoint.x)
        # Calculate the rotation angle to orient the polygon to an origin point
        orientAngle = atan2(segmentCenterPoint.y - originPoint.y, segmentCenterPoint.x - originPoint.x)
        # Get the final angle
        finalAngle = orientAngle - (pi / 2)
        if offsetAngle >= pi:
            offsetAngle -= pi
        elif offsetAngle < 0:
            offsetAngle += pi
        finalAngle += offsetAngle
        # Temporary move the point to have its rotation pivot to (0,0)
        tempX = x - segmentCenterPoint.x
        tempY = y - segmentCenterPoint.y
        # Calculate coords of the point with the rotation applied
        s = sin(finalAngle)
        c = cos(finalAngle)
        newX = tempX * c - tempY * s
        newY = tempX * s + tempY * c
        # Move the point to the initial pivot
        x = newX + segmentCenterPoint.x
        y = newY + segmentCenterPoint.y
        # Apply new coords to the vertex
        setVertexCoord(vtx, x, y)
```

I tried some examples manually and worked well, but when I tried to apply the function on thousands of segments, it seems some segment are not well oriented.

I probably missed something but i don't know what it is. Also, maybe there's a faster way to calculate it ?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

Here is a visualization to understand better the goal of the lookAt.
The goal is to find A' and B' coordinates, assuming we already know O, A and B ones. ([AB] is the segment we need to orient perpendicularly to the point O)

[image: visualization of lookAt]

Comment: What you want to get? Could you describe a goal of these manipulations? Calculations with offsetAngle look strange.

Comment: I added a picture to understand what I need to find. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Yes, all is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find positions of A' and B', you don't need rotate points (and dealt with angles at all).

```
 Find vector OC = segmentCenterPoint - originPoint
 Make normalized (unit) vector oc = OC / Length(OC)
 Make perpendicular vector  P = (-oc.Y, oc.X)
 Find CB length lCB
 Find A' = C + lCB * P
      B' = C - lCB * P
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, but I don't get why Y coordinate is before X one in your perpendicular vector ?

Comment: this is result of multiplication by pi/2 rotation matrix - like your newx,newy computations